# Why Mongodump work locally but not remotely?

Tags: linux, mongodb, linux-kernel, mongodump

I have set `bindIp: 0.0.0.0` in /etc/mongod.conf and the mongodb server is installed in a virtual machine. When I ssh inside the virtual machine if I run the following command

```
sudo mongodump --uri="mongodb://username:password@127.0.0.1:27017/database" --out ./mongodump
```

It works, it is dumped in miliseconds

But when I run from my local machine the following command:

```
sudo mongodump --uri="mongodb://username:password@<PublicIP>:27017/database" --out ./mongodump
```

Nothing happens, the shell output returns nothing.[image]

As well the database is small, it contains only one collection, and this collection has only one line of data.

Comment: 1. In the image that you upload there is no port after IP.  2. Check your server's 27017 port is open to the internet(not recommended but if you want to access remotely you need it). 3. use the command as "mongodump -vvvvv --uri=..." for printing logs while doing it's jop.

Comment: @ishak O.Thanks for helping me, sorry for the picture it was the wrong one but I have definitely typed the commands I have explained in the post. When I enter -vvvvv it says 2022-03-23T20:48:11.178+0000 will listen for SIGTERM, SIGINT, and SIGKILL

Comment: Could you try `--out=./mongodump` instead of  `--out ./mongodump` 
 (Got from https://stackoverflow.com/a/48192013/7285863)

Comment: @ishak O.I have tried --out=./mongodump and it still returns "will listen for SIGTERM, SIGINT, and SIGKILL"

Comment: can you connect via mongoshell to the remote database?

Comment: @barrypicker Nope I cannot connect, when I try on my local machine ''sudo mongo -u <user> -p <password> 18.132.212.52/database" it returns "MongoDB shell version v5.0.6
connecting to: mongodb://18.132.212.52:27017/database?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Error: couldn't connect to server 18.132.212.52:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 18.132.212.52:27017 :: caused by :: Connection timed out :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:372:17
@(connect):2:6
exception: connect failed
exiting with code 1" There is a problem with the 27017.sock

Comment: If you cannot connect via mongoshell you cannot use mongodump remotely. You must first provide connectivity.

Comment: is the remote server in AWS, Azure, or Google Cloud Platform (GCP) ?

Comment: This feels like a firewall restriction

Comment: @barrypicker mongod "$date":"2022-03-23T23:01:59.801+00:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23024,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Failed to unlink socket file","attr":{"path":"/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock","error":"Operation not permitted"}}
The problem is here, thanks for your comment because it enables me to find the source of the problem; I am going to launch an AWS EC2 Instance install the MongoDB server as explained in their official page and see how it goes because the servers I use are Virtualized Cloud Servers from the former Linux Academy(now ACloudGuru)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243257/discussion-between-aissa-and-barrypicker).